# about the iframe of fancybox?

Tags: javascript, user-interface, iframe, fancybox

I use fancybox to show a popup window from another url, using iframe.
Here is the demo of fancybox: http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/#examples

```
<a class="various fancybox.iframe" href="http://jquery.com/">Iframe</a>
```

The demo page is correct, but if I change the url of iframe to this url:  http://www.shdog.net/u/space-47012-do-blog-id-21557.html

```
<a class="various fancybox.iframe" href="http://www.shdog.net/u/space-47012-do-blog-id-21557.html
">Iframe</a>
```

...it will direct to the new page and doesn't show a popup window.

Why does this happen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the second site has this js file:

http://www.shdog.net/u/source/script_common.js

and inside that file exist this piece code

```
if (top.location != location) {
    top.location.href = location.href;
}
```

which evaluates if the site is being opened inside an `iframe` (in this case fancybox)... if so, it moves itself out of the `iframe` to the main page of the browser.

That site and others with such scripts cannot be opened in fancybox (or any other lightbox ... or inside of `html` `iframes`)